# Generate range of lists with the same number of tuples and index from list of tuples

Tags: python

Note: `string` although same value, when processed will return a different max_count value, `compute_string_and_return_integer(string)` for simplicity sake will generate random number between 3 and 9.

Given:

```
#initial input
[(string, 0),(string, 0),(string,0),(string, 1)]
```

Expected: (the max range generated depends on the previous input)

```
input = [(string, 0),(string, 0),(string,0),(string, 1)]
max_count = how_many(input) #returns (3,1) #3 is total, and 1 is the 2nd item in list to modify
generate_additional_lists(input, *max_count)
#each of generated lists will aso be used as input to generate the next batch.
[(string, 0),(string, 1),(string,0),(string, 1)] #used as input in ext run
[(string, 0),(string, 2),(string,0),(string, 1)] #used as input in next run
[(string, 0),(string, 3),(string,0),(string, 1)] #used as input again

input2 = [(string, 0),(string, 1),(string,0),(string, 1)]
max_count = how_many(input2) #returns (3,2), where 2 is index which points to 3rd tuple item in the list.
generate_additional_lists(input2, *max_count)
[(string, 0),(string, 1),(string,1),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 1),(string,2),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 1),(string,3),(string, 1)]

input3 = [(string, 0),(string, 2),(string,0),(string, 1)]
max_count = how_many(input3) #returns (7,2) where 7 is total lists to generate, 2 is index which points to 3rd tuple item in the list.
generate_additional_lists(input3, *max_count)
[(string, 0),(string, 2),(string,1),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 2),(string,2),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 2),(string,3),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 2),(string,4),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 2),(string,5),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 2),(string,6),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 2),(string,7),(string, 1)]

input4 = [(string, 0),(string, 3),(string,0),(string, 1)]
max_count = how_many(input4) #returns (4,2) where 4 is the total and 2 2 is index which points to 3rd tuple item in the list.
generate_additional_lists(input4, *max_count)
[(string, 0),(string, 3),(string,1),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 3),(string,2),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 3),(string,3),(string, 1)]
[(string, 0),(string, 3),(string,4),(string, 1)]

#we no longer have any lists with tuples that is not first or last containing 0. We stop as we have listed every possible combination.
```

The first and last tuple in the list never change and remain same throughout.
In a given list, each tuples between first and last is the focus. The number of lists generated depends on the string value as illustrated above.

I originally thought cartesian product using itertools would suffice but this requires knowing each lists of tuples at each level ahead of time. The difficulty rises when an input list determines how many other lists are generated containing tuples with incrementing index.

```
def how_many(input_list):
  for tuple_index, input in enumerate(input_list):

    if input[1] is 0: #signal to generate additional lists but how many?
       count = get_max_list_count(input[0]) #pass the string value of thhis
       return [count, tuple_index] #returns a list of how many to generate and which tuple to modify

def get_max_list_count(string_from_that_tuple):
return compute_string_and_return_integer(string_from_that_tuple) 
#for simplicitys sake, it will return a random integer between 3 and 9. The string value is not important.

def generate_additional_lists(input_list, *max_count):
#max_count[0] contains how many lists to generate
#max_count[1] contains which tuple to modify and increment it's integer value when generating the list
#generate max_count[0] number of lists with the max_count[1]th tuple containing incrementing integer
```

Comment: Why first two have three lists and the last two have 7 and 4 respectively?

Comment: Do you have a function that determines the number of lists generated? Or do you just have 4 fixed numbers for these 4 string values?

Comment: Also, how is it supposed to decide to change [1][1] in the first list, [2][1] in the second, [2,1] in the third, and [2][1] in the last?

Comment: @thefourtheye, the string value in the tuple determines how many lists are generated, and the string value is different

Comment: @dljve yes there is function which looks at the tuple (first and last tuple is always ignored), checks if it's 0, if it's zero, then it reads the string value of that tuple `(string, 0)` and returns how many lists it expects.

Comment: @ILovePython Can you please show the string value as well?

Comment: @ILovePython That seems to be an important piece of information without which we cannot solve the problem. I don't see an underlying abstract pattern which can be applied here.

Comment: @TML in the comments, the input path is different, therefore it generates different numbers. I probably shouldn't have made it a comment, I will change it now

Comment: it being a comment isn't the problem; I'm unable to discern the logical correlation

Comment: If you say there is a function that returns how many lists it expects, can you give that function, or the formula that would generate 3, 3, 7, 4 from 0, 1, 2, 3 ?

Comment: How does it know how many lists to generate? a Function reads the input list and determines how many lists it should generate, by computing the string

Comment: the whole operation is recursive, each list that is generated in return acts as an input which generates additional lists. The number of lists varies and is determined by reading that input list. So the `def how_many(input_list)` would do a loop for each tuple, it will read that tuple (not the first or last tuple) check that it's 0, read the string, and calculate how many lists to generate while incrementing that tuple's integer value.

Comment: If it was just changing the integers on the 2nd and 3rd tuple, then a couple nested for loops would do the trick, so it's more complicated than this, right? Do you have a variable amount of tuples to take care of, or something like this?

Comment: First and last tuple is always ignored. Tuple will always contain 2 values, the string which the function figures out how many lists to generate provided it's 0 (its a signal for how_many function. if it's not 0 then it will skip this tuple and move on the next tuple with 0) and generate that number of lists with incrementing tuple value....aye....it's not easy

Comment: so `def how_many(inputlist)` will loop through each tuple that is not first or last, check that it's value is 0. The first occurence of this is signal for how_many to return an integer indicating how many lists to generate. If it finds a tuple with 0, it will generate that batch, and finish. Then the generated lists each become inputs for `how_many(inputlist)` will do the same, it will look for tuple with value 0, and stop there and generate X number of lists. It will keep going until every possible combination has been generated. as I'm describing I realize how complicated it is...

Comment: I have updated the code to include those additional functions, I hope it makes sense. Basically, if there is more than one tuples with value 0 (that is not first or last item in a list), then it will keep generating list. `(1)(0)(0)(1)` could yield `(1)(1)(0)(1)` and `(1)(1)(1)(1)`, all combinations are played out, and the number of lists that should be generated depends on the first occurence of tuple with value 0, and only this tuple will be modified in the subsequent lists that is generated....whew!

Comment: How do you obtain `max_count`?

Comment: @alKid I have updated the question to include the relevant functions. max_count is a tuple containing the max number of lists to generate and also which tuple item in the list to increment the integer. Basically `how_many(list)` will produce a tuple. the `compute_string...` function takes the string value, computes how many lists to generate.

Comment: I have updated the question again, I think that there is enough information now.

Comment: I'm gonna take a break now....I think as I was describing the question in detail, the solution is slowly coming to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started writing this before you updated the question, so it's an example that doesn't have your how_many() function, but a dummy function (curiously I called that how_many too!)
See if this helps...

```
initial_input = [("This doesn't matter", 0),("Gimme 4", 0),("Maybe 8", 0),("Ignore me", 1)]

def how_many(mystring):
    return int(mystring[-1])

def display(yourlist):
    for element in yourlist:
        print element

list_of_lists = [[] for i in range(len(initial_input)-1)]
list_of_lists[0] = [list(initial_input)]

for i in range(1, len(initial_input)):
    for currlist in list_of_lists[i-1]:
        element = currlist[i]
        if element[1] == 0:
            recursions = how_many(element[0])
            additems = [currlist[:i] + [(element[0], tick)] + currlist[i+1:] for tick in range(1, recursions)]
            list_of_lists[i].extend(additems)

for i in range(len(initial_input)-1):
    print "\n"
    display(list_of_lists[i])
```

Comment: I can't believe you got it

Comment: I wish I can upvote but I can't  as I lack the reputation points. Need 15.

Comment: Glad to be of help @ILovePython! :)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, i found a recursive solution:

```
def generate_additional_lists(lst, max_count, result):
    max_count  = list(max_count)
    lst = [list(i) for i in lst]
    if max_count[0]:
        lst[max_count[1]][1]  += 1
        max_count[0] -= 1
        lst = [tuple(i) for i in lst]
        result.append(lst)
        generate_additional_lists(lst, max_count, result)
    return result
```

Demo:

```
>>> new = generate_additional_lists(input1, max_count, [])
>>> for i in new:
    print(i)


[('string', 0), ('string', 1), ('string', 0), ('string', 1)]
[('string', 0), ('string', 2), ('string', 0), ('string', 1)]
[('string', 0), ('string', 3), ('string', 0), ('string', 1)]
```

Just for fun!